# Hamiltonian Monte-Carlo with piecewise differentiable log likelihood

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, hamiltonian-monte-carlo

This is a bit of a curious situation. I have an energy function $E=S+N$ which is the sum of a smooth differentiable function $S$ and a piecewise constant "noise" function $N$. This means that on average the gradient does point in the right direction, but even a tiny step in the gradient's direction will fall on a different piece.

Is there any way to adapt HMC to handle this situation? For all practical purposes, the "noise" function is a black-box.

So far I'm thinking of using HMC updates based only on the gradient of $S$, with a MH acceptance step at the end. The only difference with regular HMC being that the acceptance ratio may not be 1 (or close to 1). Is this correct or am I missing something?

P.S. *I put "noise" in quotes because it does capture the look of the function (low spatial correlation), but it is not noise in the sense that I do not want to ignore its contribution to* the energy function.

Comment: Hamiltonian can be defined on a [symplectic manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold). A symplectic manifold must be differentiable (and smooth) to be classed as such. Therein lies the problem that you are most likely aware of. This is an interesting problem though. I would expect that one can solve the Equations of Motion (EOM) in a piecewise fashion and bootstrap them together though. I will look into this in more detail over the summer when I start my thesis on HMC.

Answer (score 1):

[This paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5801-reflection-refraction-and-hamiltonian-monte-carlo.pdf) is likely relevant.  Abstract:

> Hamiltonian Monte Carlo (HMC) is a successful approach for sampling from continuous
>   densities. However, it has difficulty simulating Hamiltonian dynamics
>   with non-smooth functions, leading to poor performance. This paper is motivated
>   by the behavior of Hamiltonian dynamics in physical systems like optics. We introduce
>   a modification of the Leapfrog discretization of **Hamiltonian dynamics on
>   piecewise continuous energies**, where intersections of the trajectory with discontinuities
>   are detected, and the momentum is reflected or refracted to compensate for
>   the change in energy.